# Finding the length of years between todays date and a column of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm new to sql so it might not be too difficult for some of you but I simply need to find the length in years between a column displaying different dates and todays date. I'm not too sure what i'm doing wrong. It gives me the error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

This is the query

```
SELECT emp_lname || ', ' || emp_fname || ' ' || emp_initial AS "Employee Full Name", 
     emp_years, 
     TO_DATE('emp_hiredate','DD/MM/YYYY')  - SYSDATE AS YEARS
FROM emp
```

Comment: Can you be quite clear on what you mean by "years" between two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem, the one throwing the error is this:

```
TO_DATE('emp_hiredate','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

You are telling the TO_DATE function that the character string literal 'emp_hiredate' is a string representation of a date, in the format 'DD/MM/YYYY'.  That is:

the character string 'em' is to be interpreted as day of the month;
the character string 'p' is expected to be a '/';
the character string '_h' is to be interpreted as the month;
the character string 'i' is expected to be a '/';
the character string 'reda' is to be interpreted as the 4-digit year;
and it doesn't know *what* to do with 'te'.

I think what you meant was

```
TO_DATE(emp_hiredate,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Notice that emp_hiredate is *not* enclosed in quotes, thus indicating "the value of the column emp_hiredate".

But note that the function TO_DATE takes a string input and converts it to _oracle's internal binary formate for DATE data types.  So this *assumes* that emp_hiredate is a varchar2, string literal *representation* of a date, and further that said string literal   *representation* of a date is in the format specified by the second argument of your call to TO_DATE.  If that is the case, you have a serious design flaw.  Dates should be stored as DATE, not VARCHAR2.

If emp_hiredate is already a DATE, then what you want is not TO_DATE, but TO_CHAR

```
TO_CHAR(emp_hiredate,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

You need to go back to the SQL Reference manual and study the difference between TO_DATE and TO_CHAR.  Also read [this](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `months_between()`:

```
select floor(months_between(sysdate, emp_hiredate) / 12)
```

Comment: Great, it it possible to add decimals with months_between?